# Why do we not say a bracha before sex?

Tags: blessing, mitzvah, sexuality, children-parenting, pru-urvu

There is a mitzvah to populate the world, pru urvu. For most mitzvot, there is a bracha we say before we do it. So why do we not say a bracha before sex? Also, whenever one benefits from anything, he says a bracha for it. So why is there no bracha for sex?

Comment: I'm regards to pru urvu, I would imagine many answers could be given - is intercourse the mitzvah act of Pru Urvu? Even if it is, can we recite a blessing over it if there is no guarantee that it will produce a viable child? Also, can you please source the notion that whenever one benefits from something, they have to make a beracha? Specifically, does one recite a beracha over something non-sustaining that they receive from themselves or another human?

Comment: Perhaps the benefit received from sex is similar to the bracha on seeing a beautiful site which is only if you haven't seen it for 30 days. (Digesting food is obviously a different kind of benefit that we make a blessing every time). I do recall seeing somewhere that some people make a shechiyanu when they get married, perhaps because it's the first time.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate. Since here's an extra question that there should be a birkas nehenin.

Answer (score 1):

The Minchas Chinuch Mitzva 1, number 14 proves from the fact that if ones children pass away without leaving children then the parent has the mitzvah of pru uruvu reinstated, that the mitzvah is not the act of sex creating the children, but rather the mitzvah is to have children in existence. (With this idea he explains why a convert who has children from before his conversion does not have the mitzvah even though they were born when he wasn't a bar chiyuva). He further explains in number 30 why kavanah is not required during sex since it's only a hechsher mitzvah (like buying an esrog) and not the actual mitzvah. (He concedes that Tosfos seems to argue with this and he says he doesn't understand)

Possibly this would explain why no blessing is required as it's only a hechsher mitzvah.